# ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to run some python on a Raspberry Pi. I am using:
Import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

I tryed installing Matplotlib many ways:
pip install matplotlib,
pip3 install matplotlib,
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib,

I keep getting the ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot

Thanks for helping

Comment: almost certainly because your pip and your python are not in the same environment.  Try `which pip` and `which python`.  Try `python -m pip install matplotlib`, which will force the install into the same environment as your python.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/faq/virtualenv_faq.html Also see here

Comment: You can also see then modern version of the above: https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/installing/index.html#frequently-asked-questions